# Why std::move can move a stack data object?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am puzzled by the following code on moving stack objects:

```
    int *pOuter = nullptr;
    {
        int j;
        std::cout << "top of the inner stack=" << &j << std::endl;
        int aData[] = {1,2,3,4,5};  // in a vanishing stack
        aData[0] = 0;  // to make sure that aData is on stack
        int *pInner = aData;
        std::cout << "Before Move: pOuter=" << pOuter << ", pInner=" << pInner << std::endl;
        pOuter = std::move(pInner);
        std::cout << "After Move: pOuter=" << pOuter << ", pInner=" << pInner << std::endl;
    }
    // aData[0] and pInner are no longer accessible
    int i;
    std::cout << "top of the outer stack=" << &i << std::endl;
    int aCover[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};  // to reclaim stack
    std::cout << "aCover=" << aCover << ", pOuter=" << pOuter << ": ";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << *(pOuter + i) << ",";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
top of the inner stack=0xb2125ff7cc
Before Move: pOuter=0, pInner=0xb2125ff7b0
After Move: pOuter=0xb2125ff7b0, pInner=0xb2125ff7b0
top of the outer stack=0xb2125ff804
aCover=0xb2125ff7d0, pOuter=0xb2125ff7b0: 0,2,3,4,5,
```

I am surprised why it works, because the stack object sData should be destroyed and covered by aCover, so that pOuter should cause segmentation failure, or at least points to sCover.  Instead, aData is not destroyed with the inner stack.

From the displayed addresses, my guess is that C++ compiler actually allocated the following  stack object before the inner stack:

```
int i; 
int aCover[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

Even so, it seems to me that pOuter is a dangling reference, and it works by chance.

Am I right?

Comment: You have undefined behavior.  `pOuter` points to garbage so you cant dereference it.

Comment: `std::move` is just a type-cast, nothing more.  For primitive types, such as pointers, a move is identical to a copy, so `pOuter = std::move(pInner);` is the same as `pOuter = pInner;` You are setting the outer pointer to point at local data that goes out of scope, leaving the outer pointer dangling.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't really move anything. It's a cast. Move assignment operators and move constructors do move, however plain pointers lack either of these, so no move takes place in your code.

Comment: this does not "work". Wrong code can produce any outcome, also the same outcome that correct code would produce. Undefined behavior is undefined. What counts is that you get guaranteed behavior from code that is free of undefined behavior. That code that has undefined behavior can produce output that looks ok isnt worth much, because once you turn on optimizations or change compiler flags or what not, the outcome can be something completely different

Comment: you can use a sanitizer to get a diagnostics that tells you whats wrong https://godbolt.org/z/K8r4Wcqrd

Comment: *Why `std::move` can move a stack data object?*  It can't.  That's not what `std::move` does.

Comment: @CPW - There is nothing in the C++ standard that says that stack space has to be reused. Not even that there has to *be* a stack. That's all up to the compiler. There is also nothing that says that the values in `aData` have to go away *immediately*, it just says that you are not allowed to use it out of scope.

Comment: Is it possible that a stack object can be moved in any C++ compiler?  For example, the temp stack object in function parameter list can be moved.  Here, it is possible that the compiler changes the stack objects creation order to accommodate move.  It is clear that the creation order of stack objects is changed, so that sData is not covered by aCover.

Comment: @cpw "move" is semantic.   It has no specific implementation or requirements.   I think you are assuming it must shift the memory from one object to another, and often times it does.   but that is not a requirement.   It's just a name... and in some ways it's poorly named.

Comment: @xaxxon
In C++11 and above, the temp object returned or on the function parameter list can be moved (so called pure rvalue).  This is probably done by adjusting the stack pointer, and possibly by adjusting the pushing order of the parameter list, so I guess that it is more than a simple cast.
For the case which I created, I am very surprised that the stack is rearranged in such a way to make move possible.  I wonder if the compiler will look at the std::move() target and make such adjustments.

Comment: @cpw One of the two of us is VERY confused about   what std::move is.   I don't think it's me.  Maybe you're thinking about elision instead?

Comment: @xaxxon I do not have a definite answer to this question.  Please see my comments below.

Comment: Here is the libstdc++ implementation of std::move -- you can clearly see it doesn't do anything at runtime: ` constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); } ` – and you can substitute your own copy of this code (with non-restricted names) and use it 100% in replacement of the std:: version and it will do exactly the same thing -- nothing at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, `std::move` is just a typecast.  So how does it work?

Well, let's take the following code as a simple example:

```
Foo x;
Foo y = x;
```

This makes a copy of `x` in `y` - i.e. it invokes `y`'s copy constructor to copy `x`.

Whereas this:

```
Foo x;
Foo y = std::move (x);
```

*moves* `x` into `y`, which, if you no longer care about `x`, is more efficient.

But - and this is key - `std::move` only does anything useful if `Foo` has a suitable move constructor, and the signature of that would be:

```
Foo &Foo (Foo &&other)
```

i.e. the parameter `other` is required to be an `rvalue`, and `std::move`, essentially, casts `x` (which starts life as an lvalue) to an rvalue, thus telling the compiler to call the move constructor rather than the copy constructor.

And that's *all* that `std::move` does.  It doesn't move anything by itself.  How could it?  It doesn't know how to, and the compiler will fall back to copying `x` if no suitable move constructor exists.  As is the case for primitive types, in particular.

Comment: In C++11 and above, the temp object returned or on the function parameter list can be moved (so called pure rvalue).  This is probably done by adjusting the stack pointer, and possibly by adjusting the pushing order of the parameter list, so I guess that it is more than a simple cast.
For the case which I created, I am very surprised that the stack is rearranged in such a way to make move possible.  I wonder if the compiler will look at the std::move() target and make such adjustments.

Comment: In C++11 and above, the following code will not result a copy:
A f() { return A(); }
A a = f();
The reason seems that when f() exits, the stack pointer does not rewind, so that the data object A in f() can be assigned to a.  So it seems not a pure type cast.

Comment: In the case which I created, it is conceivable that the C++ compiler sees the std::move() to assign an object in the inner scope to a variable in the outer scope, so that the C++ compiler actually creates {1,2,3,4,5} in the outer scope, while creating pInner and aData variable in the inner scope. If this is the case, std::move() can be applied to stack object, and pOuter is not a dangling pointer.

Comment: You still have no understanding of what std::move does based on your usage of the term in the above comment.  It is just a cast.   That's it.   It doesn't know anything about the stack or the heap nor is the stack or heap relevant to it.

Comment: @CPW These comments of yours are way off base.  Just pretend ('cos it's true) that `std::move` does nothing at all in the code you posted and maybe then you'll see it.

Comment: Until you realize "std::move doesn't move anything" then you need to keep reading and stop typing because you're just confusing yourself more.   std::move doesn't move.